# How to optimize viewmodel?

Tags: android, mvvm

I got `ViewModel` that receive one item and it need to update list in the recycler. I made it work but i am wondering if there is a cleaner solution. Im asking about `addItem` and  `deleteItem` functions

```
class MainViewModel(private val app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {

private val roomManager: RoomManager = RoomManagerImpl(app)
private val prefsManager: PrefsManager = PrefsManagerImpl(app)

private val todoItemList: MutableLiveData<List<ToDoItem>> = MutableLiveData()
val todoItemListResult: LiveData<List<ToDoItem>> = todoItemList

fun getAllItems() {
    val result = roomManager.getAllItems()
    todoItemList.postValue(result)
}

fun addItem(item: ToDoItem) {
    val list = todoItemList.value?.let {
        it.toMutableList() + item
    }
    todoItemList.postValue(list)
}

fun updateItem(item: ToDoItem) {
    roomManager.editItem(item)
}

fun deleteItem(item: ToDoItem) {
    val list = todoItemList.value?.let {
        it.toMutableList() - item
    }
    todoItemList.postValue(list)
    roomManager.deleteItem(item)
}
```

}

And here is activity observer

```
  viewModel.todoItemListResult.observe(this, Observer {
        data = it
        adapter.updateList(it)
        screenDataValidation(it)
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do You use

```
todoItemList.postValue(list)
```

The postValue() method is slower because of synchronization costs and not needed in updating from main thread. Just use **value**.

In the **deleteItem** method You set data in room and in **addItem** not?

In other things, Your code seems ok, if You want to avoid unnecessary structures, I would recommend write like that:

```
if (list.isNullOrEmpty())
    return

todoItemList.value = todoItemList.value + item
roomManager.add(item)
```